# Can I create a property on a JavaScript object that's new every time it's referenced?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, the output will be the same.

```
function dateObject() {
    this.date = new Date();
}

var wrapper = {
    dateObj: new dateObject()
};

console.log(wrapper.dateObj.date);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(wrapper.dateObj.date);
}, 3000);
```

I actually stumbled across this checking to make sure that the value of the property doesn't change, but now I'm curious. Is there a way to have a property that isn't a function, but rather the evaluation of a function, that will be new every time?  I ask because you can do it in other languages (think `System.DateTime` in C#).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Here's an example:

```
function DateObject(time) {
    this._date = new Date(time);
}

Object.defineProperty(DateObject, "now", {
    get: function () {
        return new DateObject(Date.now());
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(DateObject.prototype, "time", {
    get: function () {
        return this._date.getTime();
    }
});
```

Then each time you reference this property it will equal the result of the function evaluation of `get`:

```
// calls new DateObject(Date.now()), like Date.Now in C#
var d = DateObject.now;
// calls d._date.getTime()
d.time;
```

As you can see, `now` is defined on `DateObject`. This acts like a static property. Then `time` is defined on the object's prototype which means it will be a property for instances of `DateObject`.

**Note:** Research the `enumerable` and `configurable` properties for the third argument of `Object.defineProperty`. They can be useful.

Comment: Note that this is exactly what C# does too in `DateTime` which OP referenced.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum not quite. DateTime.Now is a property, not a static method. It's the difference between defining a get on a property that invokes a method, as opposed to defining a property that is a method that has to be invoked.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sure you can change it if you'd like. I just gave a random example and used the current time because the current time changes frequently. I know it doesn't really make sense in the context of the original object, but it was just to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: @moarboilerplate the JS terminology is a bit different - but JS has properties with getters and setters just like C# :) (as this answer demonstrates)

Comment: @moarboilerplate properties are functions under the hood in c#

Comment: @DavidSherret true but you don't have to invoke them with `()`

Comment: I've edited the question - it now looks similar to the C# example OP was describing - feel free to revert/edit :)

Comment: @moarboilerplate yeah, it's just nice syntactic sugar. If you want something nicer in JavaScript you can use Typescript. [See here](http://goo.gl/QrAoKi)

Comment: Note `enumerable: false` is the default, so it is not needed.

Comment: @Oriol thanks, I had them both set to true originally. I just removed both of them for brevity and stated that people should go research `enumerable` and `configurable` to see if they want to use them.